# How can I concatenate two variables, containing integers, with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

In my html I am trying to do the following

```
{{firstvar + secondvar | myFilter}}
```

However inside my filter it is only getting the second variable here. How can I concat these two variable to be sent to the filter?

**UPDATE**

This is weird, if I add an empty string to the middle it works,

```
{{firstvar + "" + secondvar | myFilter}}
```

Though it seems there should be a better solution

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/lqN6OGpavfPaR4VwsERe?p=preview can you please post a plunker that shows the problem?

Comment: What are the values in firstvar and secondvar?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat They are integers. Probably why haimlit's is working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a hunch that this isn't working for you because you are using numbers here instead of strings. The angular `{{...}}` syntax allows us to describe a JavaScript expression we want evaluated when angular digests the DOM. The key here is that angular is evaluating the expression using (nearly) the same rules that would be used in a plain old JavaScript expression. You can see the caveats to this rule [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

To illustrate this point, let's imagine:

```
var firstvar = 1;
var secondvar = 2;
```

Now, considering the values we just assigned to `firstvar` and `secondvar`, what would we expect the value in `result` in the following expression to be?

`var result = firstvar + secondvar`

Well, since we know these are both numbers, the obvious answer is that `result` equals 3 (1 + 2 = 3, amazing!).

The point here is that when the JavaScript engine evaluates `{{ firstvar + secondvar | myFilter }}` it sees two numbers, not two strings. So using the `+` operator will cause an *addition* not a string concatenation.

As far as why you aren't getting the correctly evaluated expression value inside your filter, I am not sure. From my quick testing, and from skimming through the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter), I can't find a reason why you are having this issue. The syntax for using a filter is:

```
{{ expression | filter }}
```

So any valid JavaScript expression (that follows Angular's [rules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)) should work. In other words, the expression you posted above is perfectly valid. In fact, in my own plunker, I created a similar situation to what you described and I am not seeing any issues. It is evaluating the expression as expected, and I see the correct value in `myFilter`: [example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qiQhZli511VyPJVkIFUi?p=preview).

The reason the concatenation is working when you use the expression `{{ firstvar + "" + secondvar | myFilter }}` is because your `""` expression is creating an empty string object. When the JavaScript engine sees `+` in conjunction with this new string object, it attempts to serialize `firstvar` and `secondvar` (in other words turn them into strings). This results in what I would imagine was your original intent, that is to concatenate the *serialized* values of `firstvar` and `secondvar`. In my view this is a completely valid way of causing a string concatenation, as the result is equivalent to calling the `toString()` method for each variable. If you prefer, you could also call the `toString()` method for each variable directly like so:

```
{{ firstvar.toString() + secondvar.toString() | myFilter }}
```

This is essentially equivalent, except that you are avoiding the unnecessary creation of the empty string object.

So, in short, you can use either of these two expression to achieve a string concatenation:

```
{{ firstvar + "" + secondvar | myFilter }}
{{ firstvar.toString() + secondvar.toString | myFilter }}
```

Of course, this is all assuming that you are using a type other than `string` (in which case no serialization would be necessary, it's already a string!) Anyway, hope this clears some things up.

Comment: I believe you are correct on this. For some reason it should have occurred to me that it would be adding them together as integers like javascript would. I was assuming that all variables inside brackets would be treated as strings if I used the +.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried this

```
{{(firstvar + secondvar) | myFilter}}
```

?

I would do it myself, but I don't have an AngularJS environment available right now, sry.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$parent.$eval(firstvar+secondvar)`

Comment: That looked promising but its returning undefined in the filter. I tried it without the parent also.

Comment: Try `$parent.$eval('firstvar+secondvar')`?

Comment: Nope that just returns the second variable again

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me

```
<p> {{(firstvar| myFilter) + (secondvar | myFilter)}}</p>
```

I think you should use parentheses at correct place.